# Swift error declaring delegate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, protocols

I'm new in swift and I'm studying the delegate and protocols. In my test application I'm using this protocol declaration (in ViewController1) and I have this code:

```
 import UIKit

//Protocol declaration

protocol viewController1Delegate

{

    func didFinish(controller:ViewController1,text:String)
}
```

//ViewController1 class

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

//delegate declaration for viewController1
var delegate:ViewController1? = nil


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    valore.text=valoreInput
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func doneWithOK(sender: AnyObject) {

    delegate?.didFinish(self,"done")
}
}
```

My problem is XCode show me an error: ViewController1 does not have a member named didFinisch. What is wrong in my code? Someone can help me to understand the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delegate` should be `viewController1Delegate?` and not `ViewController1?`.

Comment: Yes!!! (so stupid!) sorry... it's correct!  I have to use viewController1Delegate and not viewController1